# what does else if (!*p) mean in this code

Tags: if-statement

I am  trying to understand how this program works and i found something that i dont understand it was in this part

```
if (!isempty(stack) || *p) {
      puts("Invalid parenthesis expression");

      while (! isempty(stack))
        pop(&stack);
    }
    else if (!*p)
      puts("Valid parenthesis expression");
```

The full coding is here

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct data{
  char parent;
  struct data *next;
} DATA;

void push(DATA **stack, char parentheses);
int isempty(DATA *stack);
void pop(DATA **stack);
int top(DATA *stack);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  DATA *stack = NULL;
  char parentheses[100];
  char * p;

  while (fputs("Enter parentheses: ", stdout),
         (scanf(" %99[^\n]", parentheses) == 1) && strcmp(parentheses, "-1")) {
    for (p = parentheses; *p; ++p) {
      if  ((*p == '{') || (*p == '[') || (*p == '('))
        push(&stack, *p);
      else {
        char o;

        if (*p == '}')
          o = '{';
        else if (*p == ')')
          o = '(';
        else if (*p == ']')
          o = '[';
        else
          o = 0;

        if (isempty(stack) || (top(stack) != o))
          break;

        pop(&stack);
      }
    }

    if (!isempty(stack) || *p) {
      puts("Invalid parenthesis expression");

      while (! isempty(stack))
        pop(&stack);
    }
    else if (!*p)
      puts("Valid parenthesis expression");
  }

  return 0;
}

void push(DATA **stack, char parentheses) {
    DATA *node = malloc(sizeof(DATA));

    node->parent = parentheses;
    node->next = *stack;
    *stack = node;
}

int isempty(DATA *stack) {
  return (stack == NULL);
}

void pop(DATA **stack) {
  DATA *temp = *stack;

  *stack = (*stack)->next;
  free(temp);
}

int top(DATA *stack) {
  return stack->parent;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to speciffy language first. I guess its C or C++. If it is correct then *p is pointer

Comment: @Kandy: the fact that it's using `puts` almost certainly makes it C, since no C++ coder in their right mind would use the legacy C facilities in preference to the C++ ones :-)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Which **exact** parts are unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `!*p`, when applied to a pointer variable `p`, will dereference the pointer the logically negate it. In this case, it appears that `p` is a `char *` traversing through a string, meaning it will get the character at that location and give you:

- zero if it was non-zero; or
- one if it was zero.

In other words, it's (rather ugly) C shorthand for:

```
if (*p == '\0')
```

meaning the pointer has reached the end of the C string.

---

From a higher-level view, this program appears to be evaluating an infix expression like:

```
{[(3 + 7) / 2] + 6}
```

and using a stack to store the different parentheses. It's doing this to check that the parentheses are balanced.

As each opening parenthesis is found, it is pushed on to the stack. Then, whenever you find a closing parenthesis, you check that both:

- the stack isn't empty; and
- the popped value off the stack is the opening equivalent of your closing one.

Anything else is an error.

Finally, at the *end* the expression, the stack should be empty. Otherwise, there were less closing parentheses than opening ones.

Comment: oh i see so it mean that the char is at the end :D ok thx for your explanation